# Ошибка AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Firefox'

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Установила selenium, один раз запустился но потом выскакивает ошибка. Что не так?

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Указываем полный путь к geckodriver.exe на вашем ПК.
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:!!!1\1prog\vk!main.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from selenium import webdriver   File "C:\Users\Ulia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver__init__.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa   File "C:\Users\Ulia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 36, in 
>       from .service import Service   File "C:\Users\Ulia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from selenium.webdriver.common import service   File "C:\Users\Ulia\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Firefox('c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\') AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no
>   attribute 'Firefox'

Comment: Указывался путь до бинарника Firefox? 
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

Comment: Покажите весь код пожалуйста. В трассировке ошибки переменная браузера называется `browser`, а в примере кода вы пишете `driver`. И трассировка ошибки сообщает, что вы добавили аргумент 'Firefox' во время инициализации браузера, на который собственно и выпадает except.

Answer (score 0):

Зашла и удалила папки с названием "selenium" ..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\
потом через pip install selenium,pip3 install selenium
установила и заработало